# C# Regex - Get each words including spl characters to an string array

Tags: c#, regex

In my C# app, i am using an expression as shown below:

```
Value(Value1(A+B) + Value2(C, D)) / Value4(B*D).
```

Is there anyway to get splited the expression including the splitted char as shown below

```
Value
(
Value1
(
A
+
B
)
```

Similarly each words with special chars like '(', ')', '+', '-', etc in a string array

Comment: Why not use a mathematical expression parser library instead of regex?

Comment: thanks for the reply. cud you please specify ?

Comment: Specify what? You can look up "mathematical expression parser .NET" - there are several out there, including on codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

The closest one comes with regular expressions is using .Nets balanced matching regex:

1. [Balanced Matching](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx)
2. [Matching Balanced Constructs with .NET Regular Expressions](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2005/02/20/377025.aspx)
3. [Fun With .NET Regex Balancing Groups](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/balancing-groups)

   Otherwise you may need something that handles it such as the [Gardens Point Lexical Analyer](http://gplex.codeplex.com/) instead.